# How to populate a single-dimension array with result of a query FOR DB2?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, db2

I need to populate a single-dimension array with a result set from a select query.

I have created the array type using:
create or replace type UR.array_traveler_id as BIGINT array[];

and in the stored proc I am using the following SELECT INTO query:

```
SELECT TRAVELER_ID bulk collect 
INTO arraylist 
FROM UR.APPLIEDPROFILE 
where TRAVELERPROFILEID = p_travelerid;
```

I have declared the arraylist as:
DECLARE arraylist UR.array_traveler_id;

I dont know what is the problem but DB2 is not allowing me to use BULK COLLECTION.

The error which I am getting is "An unexpected token "collect" was found following.....SQLSTATE=42601"

Please suggest a way around.

Answer (score 0):

The BULK COLLECT clause is only valid in PL/SQL context. You should be running DB2 9.7 fix pack 1 or later, the database must be created in the Oracle compatibility mode, and the procedure must be written in PL/SQL, not DB2 SQL PL.

Comment: That depends on which of the prerequisites are not met.

Comment: I am using DB2 9.7.0.2 pack 2. I have to populate an array from the resultset of a select statement. Please suggest?